# Weird Cloudfoundry error

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I have a simple node app that I am trying to host on cloudfoundry. I am using the node module [srand](https://github.com/isaacs/node-srand).

When I visit the url, I get this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module './build/default/srand.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/UnfoundedAccusations-0-8f4d453d8731dd95a14f10aeddc17eae/app/node_modules/srand/index.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

Comment: this might help http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/12/19/recent-changes-in-node-js-modules-support/

Comment: @vinayr That worked great. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently cloudfoundry made some changes for Node.js modules support. Have a look at here http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/12/19/recent-changes-in-node-js-modules-support/

Comment: It turns out I just needed to run the command `npm shrinkwrap` before deploying. It must have been some type of version mismatch on their end.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably installed the module globally, which is fine for local development but you need to deploy the application *with* the module.

Before deploying via vmc, run `npm install` in the project directory.

Comment: Nope, I have a `package.json` with my dependencies listed and the packages are all present in the `node_modules` folder.